# Ajax request not being sent

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm currently creating a function that makes a POST request to an application.  I have my JSON string correctly set up, but when I use the debugger and monitor network activity, I never see any request being sent from my browser.  Here is a breakdown of my code.  I had to do some trickery, as this is a PoC code, and it originally dealt with a jsp page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#myForm").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var myJsonObject = new Object();
    //set up my object and stringify it into myString

    sendDataToServer(myString);     
    });

  function sendDataToServer(jsonString) {
     $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       data: jsonString,
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       url: "https://my.target.server.com"
       dataType : 'json',
       processdata: true,
       success: eval("successMessage"),
       error: eval("failureMessage")
       });
    }

 function successMessage() {
    alert("Post was successful");
  }

 function failureMessage() {
    alert("Post failed");
  }
});
```

Now, my ajax call fails (still dealing with credential issues and certs), but I can't even see any request being sent from the start.  Is my ajax call wrong, or is there some other problem?  If I am denied access to the server due to cert issues, would it fail when trying to set up a connection to the server before sending any request?

And for some extra info, I do see the failureMessage() alert when I submit my form, so I know it is at least calling the ajax function.

Comment: **eval is evil.** Don't use eval in this context. Use a closure.

Comment: @LorenzMeyer Sorry, very new to AJAX calls.  I looked up closures, and is it just defining the function in the success param?

Comment: Right. Just call the function. Don't eval it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can not** send cross-domain AJAX requests.

Seems like "https://my.target.server.com" is a different domain than the one where your script is running.
Other popular solutions would be `JSONP`, `iframe` or `flash`. Or using your back end as a proxy.

See [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=cross%20domain%20ajax) and [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=jsonp).
If target server is also owned by you, you may want to examine [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

Comment: Learn something new everyday, thanks! I will try it out.

Answer (score 0):

This may be because of cross site domains. By default it is set to false. If url is a different domain you need to switch it to true.

As per JQuery documentation

```
crossDomain (default: false for same-domain requests, true for cross-domain requests)
Type: Boolean
If you wish to force a crossDomain request (such as JSONP) on the same domain, set the value of    crossDomain to true. This allows, for example, server-side redirection to another domain. (version added: 1.5)
```

Hope this be of some help
Happy Learning :)

Answer (score 0):

See this to illustrate what I meant with *closures*. I also integrated the answer the others gave.

```
function sendDataToServer(jsonString) {
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       data: jsonString,
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       url: "https://my.target.server.com"
       dataType : 'json',
       processdata: true,
       crossDomain: true,
       success: function() {alert("Post was successful")},
       error: function(){alert("Post failed")}
    }
}
```